# Installed Glade3 with macports but cant open it?

Tags: macos, macports

Looking to develop a simple shell for my perl scripts and I installed glade3 on my mac with macports, but I have no idea how to open it... tried executing the program in shell but gives me GTK warning: cannot open display. Also I cant find the program in my applications menu...

Any suggestion is welcome!